# Boxing on stack for function calls

Tags: c#

According to C# documentation boxing is done on heap. What i am wondering about is whether it's a good idea in theory to allocate box on stack in case boxing is done for a function argument. And move that box to heap later only if that box gets referenced from heap. I think it would be a significant optimization for function calls with object-type arguments and the ones with variable number of arguments. Please enlighten me on this matter.

Comment: This concept is not new. In fact, there's a whole thing in C/C++ on when it's better to allocate memory on the stack or on the heap. In C#, however, you don't have this freedom of choice. All value types are allocated on the stack, and all reference types are allocated on the heap (simplified answer). As for why the decision was made to design C# (and .NET) in this way, I recommend reading [Eric Lippert's articles on the stack](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/04/27/the-stack-is-an-implementation-detail-part-one/).

Comment: I'd also like to draw attention to the point near the end of Part 1 of that series that (correctly) points out that in the vast majority of cases in the vast majority of programs, the performance gain in allocating an object on the stack vs. on the heap or vice versa would be virtually non-existant compared to the bottlenecks in the rest of the code.

Comment: Abion47, it's not about what i can do in C#, it's about runtime boxing always on heap, while in my opinion in case of function arguments its better to do boxing on stack.

Comment: Abion47, allocating on stack is a lot cheaper that allocating on heap. And in a high performance code for a function call it will be one of major bottlenecks.